1 External SSD with OS and all files, used by 2 Macs, possible?
I have an iMac M1 at home, and a Mac Mini M2 at an office, instead of having 2 completely separate operating systems, programs, files, etc I am wondering if it is possible to clone my iMac's internal drive to an external SSD, then simply boot from it on the iMac at home, and when I go to the office take it with me and boot from it on the Mac Mini. Eliminating the need to maintain 2 computers.

Is it possible?
If it is, i'm wondering if it may cause any issues, e.g. one day the OS thinks it's on an iMac, next day it's a Mac Mini, different screens connected, etc.


Does your "office" location have security policies which would forbid this?

Do you need to carry your whole Mac around with you or would it be enough to to have your documents and source code on a portable drive?

On recent Macs such as these, you have the issue that some important stuff is not on disk but in the secure enclave in the M1/M2 chip, such as fingerprints, encryption keys, etc. While you can do without, it could reduce security and/or functionality. It's probably easier to move the Mini or switch to some flavour of a MacBook.

@gilby no it's my office so no

@nohillside the idea was to have the identical setup, programs, settings, even stuff like mamp pro, composer repos, nodejs repos, etc - i know i would probably better with a macbook and just using it for both scenarios, however I already have an iMac i love with everything on

Two options come to mind: a: setting one Mac up for remote access and using it also from the other location. b: scripting all installs and putting scripts as well as config files into GitHub or similar.

I've had difficulty getting my 2018 Mac Mini intel to boot Mojave externally.  I found it impossible with Ventura.

While this may be possible, I'm not sure that it would necessarily reduce the amount of "maintenance" that you need to do. Firstly, there are aspects of the Mac's security that make this very difficult. There are also hardware-specific configuration files on a system disk. The computer will use different networks, for starters, , which you would have to switch over. Even sharing a user account between two Macs can be problematic. Different window positions are the least of your problems! On the whole, I would strongly advise against this.
(Dissenting opinions detailing the complete steps required are welcome.)

"Eliminating the need to maintain 2 computers."
There are plenty of ways to reduce any maintenance. Firstly, make sure that in System Settings > General > Software Update > Security Responses, you have turned on automatic updates for apps and OS.
You can synchronise the contents of your Documents folder, either by using iCloud (or Dropbox, or OneDrive..), or by using third-party sync apps. Some of these can sync Macs across different locations. These include SyncThing, Resilio Sync, Chronosync, GoodSync, and many more.
That should probably reduce the amount of tech maintenance/admin that you will need to do.

macOS handles hardware-specific settings just fine (ByHost), in fact it has support for network-based home folders. I don't understand why different networks will be a problem, laptops exist just fine.  Having a single source of truth (ext SSD) with a backup is a far better option than cloud syncing, which for iCloud at least has constant issues with conflicts. Not to mention the inability to store multiple files, or the horror of trying to sync apps or brew/port. Only real issue would be different architectures, but OP doesn't have that issue. Otherwise all macOS System folders are identical.

@At0micMutex Can you assign secure/bootstrap tokens for different devices on the same volume?

How do auto updates reduce maintenance? Most maintenance have nothing to do with base system.

@hym3242 I'm presuming that "maintenance" means "having to do admin stuff sorting out the computer", of which updating is a part. (And to be honest, I suspect that a single-drive setup, if possible, would probably still require as much, if not more, maintaining.

By maintenance I meant effectively installing the same apps on both, having to create a PHP server on both and ensure the settings are consistent between both machines, stuff like that

One option of iCloud is to make your documents folder be on the cloud. It's pretty nicely set up for this if you're willing to pay for the storage.

I've done this with various versions of MacOS, and it works, but it's not a good idea.
The best outcome was with a copy of 10.5 (Leopard).  I've got some legacy software that won't run on anything but PowerPC, so I installed the OS and software on an external hard drive, and it's spent the past decade or so bouncing from one computer to another as hardware fails.
I've also done it with 10.14 (Mojave).  I needed two copies of my development environment to perform some long-running tasks, so I imaged the original machine to an external SSD, plugged it into a spare computer, and started it up.  The clone, despite being a more powerful machine, initially ran slower because the OS spent about 36 hours doing something that involved heavy disk access.

While external SSDs are really fast these days the performance won't be as good as the internal SSDs. What you're wanting to do isn't even necessary if you use iCloud drive. Just install the same apps on each Mac and allow iCloud drive to keep your data in sync. This is something I have done for several years. I have had a desktop Mac and a MacBook Pro for a long time. Because of iCloud Drive, I never had to worry about which Mac I had certain files stored on. Everything was on both Macs. When I bought my MacBook Pro last year, I didn't do a data migration. I just signed into iCloud and within minutes everything I have stored in iCloud drive was available to me. I installed my apps and all was well. I stopped using the data migration assistant a long time ago. I don't mind installing apps on a new Mac. It also gives  me an opportunity to just not install apps I don't need anymore. Apple has made it almost impossible to make bootable clones of macOS, so what you are asking for may not even be possible or easy to maintain.
